Power BI Get File of Export to File in Group - NodeJS / React
I am trying to figure out how to stream/download the exported PDF file from a Power BI API Export call. I'm using a NodeJS backend with a React frontend. Here's what I'm trying to do in the backend:
const queryResults = await fetch(`https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${workspaceId}/reports/${reportId}/exports/${exportId}/file`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/pdf',
        authorization: accessToken
      }
    });

    return queryResults;

For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-file-of-export-to-file-in-group
All I get is a JSON response of { size: 0, timeout: 0}. I am able to download the exported PDF file when using Postman going straight to the Power BI API but not when calling my API. I am able to perform the first two steps of the Export process (create the export and poll for the completion of the export) so I know my connection to the Power BI API is valid.
I've found some C# samples online for streaming the PDF file back to the browser, but nothing for NodeJS. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.
